# Перехват трафика в текущем процессе

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winsock2

Куда ведут функции WSASend, WSASendto, sendto и т. д.? В интернете пишут, что WSASend — это обертка над функцией send, но когда я перехватываю send, ничего не происходит. Я уверен, что есть одна скрытая функция, которая вызывается при вызове этих функций. Как его найти и есть ли он там? Что-то вроде

```
      internal_send
  _________|_________
 |                   |
WSASend             send
```

Comment: What's the reason to ask questions in English on Russian SO?

Comment: Простите, я перепутал stackoverflow. Сейчас все исправлю.

Comment: я посмотрел поверхностно - и не нашел, где пишут что "WSASend — это обертка над функцией send". Хотя перекопал несколько страниц с описаниями, относящимися к WSASend. Не могли бы Вы привести ссылку?

Comment: https://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=345043
5 сообщение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обсуждения на программистских форумах, аж 2005 годом повеяло.

`WSASend` действительно не обертка, скорее всего эти функции просто разделяют часть кода под капотом. Да и тогда уж это `send` должен был быть оберткой над `WSASend`, т.к. эта функция - частный случай более сложной функции.

Если хотите нащупать этот `internal_send`, я бы вооружился отладчиком вроде x64dbg, брякнулся на каждой из этих функций и сгенерировал бы трассу до переключения в ядро. Если наше предположение верно, то трасса должна оканчиваться одинаковой последовательностью инструкций, начиная с какого-то `call`. Это и будет искомая `internal_send`.

Comment: У меня есть x64dbg, но я пока не научился делать трассировку а понятных уроков в интернете найти не смог :( Но спасибо большое, я что-то попробую сделать.